# Issue importing createRoot from react-dom/client

Tags: reactjs

After using create-react-app and updating the index.js ReactDOM.render to React 18 I get this error: "Warning: You are importing createRoot from 'react-dom' which is not supported. You should instead import it from 'react-dom/client'".

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Switch from './components/Switch';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Switch />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: I think your main issue was to not using `createRoot` imported from `react-dom/client`. You were still using `ReactDOM.createRoot` instead of just `createRoot ` in line 6

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The error message received indicates that you should be importing the `createRoot` method from `react-dom/client` instead of from `react-dom`.

To fix the issue, modify your import statement for `createRoot` to look like this :

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
```

So the modified code should be :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Switch from './components/Switch';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Switch />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: How to import it without Node (plain JS)?

Comment: In addition with the answer:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#react-dom-client

Comment: This answer adds complexity to answering and kills simplicity. To import full Lib should be a choice not an obligation. As a straight answer, I would use `createRoot` imported from the `react-dom/client` to create the `root` element. Also, I don't know what do you mean by when you say `Recently createRoot have been moved to react-dom/client in React 18 RC (RC 1)` while user has had already used it in the code.

Comment: @ArvindK. I understand the concern about importing the entire React-DOM library just to use the createRoot method. It is true that this could potentially add unnecessary complexity to the codebase and increase bundle size. The answer has been updated. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 5):

For all the typescript users, add this if you're getting the classic *"no types found for this module" warning.*

**src/react-app-env.d.ts**

```
declare module "react-dom/client" {
  // typing module default export as `any` will allow you to access its members without compiler warning
  var createRoot: any;
  export {createRoot};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure your react-dom version is `"^18.0.0"`

Comment: For typescript, we also need to update @types/react-dom package to "^18.0.0".

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Switch from './components/Switch';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Switch />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I used `createRoot` imported from the `react-dom/client` and removed the import of unused `ReactDOM`

Answer (score 0):

Now in React 18+ you can do this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import Switch from './components/Switch'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Switch />
    </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Comment: Naming it `ReactDOMClient` would have saved you!

Answer (score 0):

If you `import ReactDOM` and never use it in your code, you will receive a warning when compiling your code. As I am using `Provider` and `reduxJS`, my code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'; 
import App from './components/App';
import reducers from './reducers';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';


const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  middleware: [reduxThunk]
});

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Necesitas agregar '/client' cuando importas 'ReactDOM'**

**You need to add '/client' when you import 'ReactDOM'.**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Switch from './components/Switch';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Switch />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```