# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dom/client'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, react-redux, microservices

I have following error when use react-dom/client

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in src/index.tsx:2:28

TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dom/client'. 'C:/Users/Mohamad/Desktop/HIS/Administration/Administration/Administration/Administration.Endpoints.WebUI/ClientApp/node_modules/react-dom/client.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-dom/client';`
    1 | import * as React from 'react';
  > 2 | import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
      |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | import App from './App';
    4 |
    5 |
```

Comment: Have you installed `@types/react-dom` as it suggests?

Comment: Getting same error even after installing types

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm running into this problem as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809050

Comment: Actually, better to do this https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/43848#issuecomment-1097722636

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Install @types/react-dom with @latest

```
 npm i @types/react-dom@latest
```

Comment: That worked for me, although I'd like to suggest installing types as a dev-dependency only, such as: `npm i -D @types/react-dom@latest`

Comment: Types should be installed as devDependencies. `yarn add -D @types/react-dom`

Answer (score 9):

Error message actually states the solution:

You need to install the package or define in `.d.ts` file

However for my case, I had to do both of them to resolve the issue.

Install the package:

```bash
npm install @types/react-dom
```

Define in `.d.ts`

```
declare module 'react-dom/client';
```

Comment: Briliiant! Adding module declaration on my `react-app-env.d.ts` file help me fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Sabri and David answer, when using yarn you can run

```
yarn add @types/react-dom
```

That works for yarn and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As the error trace suggests you need to install an additional package. If you keep getting the same error you should post your `package.json`here.

Even though a similar answer was provided but I'd suggest installing the package with the --save-dev flag.

Hence:
`npm i --save-dev @types/react-dom`

Answer (score -2):

Instead of ratholing on that, I added the following statement to the tsconfig.json file to disable the ‘any’ type errors:

"noImplicitAny": false