# How do I get rid of Warning:ReactDom.render is no longer supported error for React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I want to get rid of the console error that says

``` react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: ``https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot ```

I tried to paste suggested code on React's webpage How to Upgrade to React 18.

`// After`
`import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';`
`const container = document.getElementById('app');`
`const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript`
`root.render(<App tab="home" />);`

But that didn't help.

I also, tried removing `import ReactDOM from "react-dom"; ReactDOM.render(<Booklist/>, document.getElementById('root'));` from my code and replacing it with

`import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';`

`const container = document.getElementById('root');`

`const root = createRoot(container);`

`root.render(<Booklist />);` but that didn't work either.

Here's my code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//CSS
import './index.css';

function BookList() {
    return (
        <section className="booklist">
            <Book />
            <Book />
            <Book />
            <Book />
            <Book />
            <Book />
            <Book />
            <Book />
            <Book />
        </section>
    );
}

const Book = () => {
    return (
        <article className="book">
            <Image />
            <Title />
            <Author />
        </article>
    );
};

const Image = () => (
    <img
        src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/917y6YbgeDL._AC_UY218_.jpg"
        alt=""
    />
);

const Title = () => <h1>The Bostonians</h1>;
const Author = () => (
    <h4 style={{ color: '#617d98', fontSize: '0.75rem', marginTop: '0.25rem' }}>
        Henry James
    </h4>
);
ReactDOM.render(<BookList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Change render from

```
ReactDOM.render(<BookList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

to

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: I got the following error-----Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

[eslint] 
src\index.js
  Line 50:4:  'App' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Here's my github for [link](https://github.com/eudeamonism/Book_List.git)

Comment: You have to use <BookList /> instead of App

Comment: I gave that a shot, and thanks for your help, but i got the following error despite the page rendering ---react-dom.development.js:86 
        
       Warning: You are importing createRoot from "react-dom" which is not supported. You should instead import it from "react-dom/client".

Comment: Found a related issue on that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71743492/issue-importing-createroot-from-react-dom-client